# Android: Reusability of code by creating a library project

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, reusability, library-project

I am trying to create a library project to reuse certain things which are common in many applications like splash screen, login screen, asynchronous thread calls for getting data from a URL, custom listView, DAO files, etc.

I want to import this library and then just call the method from this library. Is it possible? If yes, then how to approach for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what IDE are You using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Why my question is downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create your own library if you are using Eclipse IDE.

```
Create new project and mark that project as library.As shown in the image
```

[image]

```
  Create your classes and method in this project.
```

Now, How to use or include this library in your other projects. See this snapshot

[image]

Note: Make sure your both projects are present in same workspace.

After adding your library project you can use methods defined in the classes of your Library.

Comment: If you have any query please let me know.And sorry if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: "Note" part of the answer was very important. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** if using Android Studio: mark your module as library using Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Once build, you'll find an AAR file in `build/outputs/aar/`.

You can then include it in other projects using Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name: 'filename', ext: 'aar')
}
```

**No** if using Eclipse: because the ADT plugin does not support it and probably won't since Android Studio 1.0.0 final came out.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59183

Comment: Thank you shkschneider, but I am using eclipse.

Comment: Then it means, I have to write all the same methods in every application every time? No near solution?

Comment: At least not that I'm aware of (using Eclipse+ADT). The AAR format came out with Gradle (from Android Studio). Android Studio is final now and Google is working on it more than ADT.